# javascript get style and increment

Tags: javascript, css, attributes, onclick, increment

I'm trying to make a slider that changes the margin-left attribute in the external css onclick. So I need to get the attribute and then set the new attribute.

here is my code:

```
<style>
#divName
 {
  margin-left:20px;
 }
</style>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  

                var x = document.getElementById(divName);

            if (x.currentStyle)
            {
                var y = x.currentStyle[marginLeft];
            }
            else (window.getComputedStyle)
            {
                var y = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(x,null).getPropertyValue(marginLeft);
            }

                y = y + 20;

                document.getElementById(divName).style.marginLeft = y .'px';

    </script>
```

thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript, the `.` operator does not concatenate strings.

Use the `+` operator instead:

```
document.getElementById(divName).style.marginLeft = y + 'px';
```

You also probably need to pass `marginLeft` as a string, not a name (unless there is a variable in scope that is named `marginLeft` and set to `"marginLeft"`):

```
var y = x.currentStyle["marginLeft"];
```

And:

```
var y = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(x, null).getPropertyValue("marginLeft");
```